# wordpress onpage .csv export button based on post types

Tags: php, wordpress, csv

I would like to create a URL of current wordpress data based on `post_type` because I would like to include it as an on-page hyperlink. I have tried various plugins and tutorials but hadn't had such luck. Any suggestions?

It would be great to maintain a URL called `export.php` and have trigger download of current `.csv` file of `post_type` wordpress db area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the [endpoint API](https://make.wordpress.org/plugins/2012/06/07/rewrite-endpoints-api/) was made for things like this. Take a look at some JSON endpoint [examples](https://encrypted.google.com/#q=wordpress+json+endpoint). Assuming example.com/books/ is a post type archive, create a csv (or export) endpoint for that post type by defining it in your [register_post_type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#Arguments) function (the rewrite arg). When the endpoint is visited, you could for example use the [template_redirect](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/template_redirect) hook to redirect to a template that builds and downloads the CSV.